# Find same value in different column and print data of adjacent column using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 columns "Column1", "MOVIE_ID", "AVERAGE_RATING" and "RESULT".

I want to check if the row in Column1 has the same data in "MOVIE_ID", and if the data is the same, I want to print show the AVERATING_RATING data again in "RESULT".

[image: excel]

For example: if A2 matches any data in MOVIE_ID (in this case it will match B11), I want to print the adjacent AVERAGE_RATING (C11) in the result (D11) which is one the same row of the found MOVIE_ID.

I have this currently `=VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$5001;3)` but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's more like =VLOOKUP(B2;$A$2:$C$5001;3) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easily possible, in the way you ask, because you want to use a variable field in the column A to match a field in the column B and display the result in the same row of B. But you cant set a variable result cell. So the result will be displayed in the cell where the function is.

But fortunately we have an equality relation, so we can switch the variable field and the search column. So we got the function:
`=VLOOKUP(B2; $A$2:$C$11; 3; FALSE)`.
B2 is the variable lookup value.
$A$2:$C$11 is the constant Matrix.
3 is the column index (beginning by 1) of the result value.
FALSE is for a exact match.

So the value of B2 will be searched in the column A.
IF there was a equal value found, the value from the C column will be displayed as a result
ELSE #N/A will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you! That helps alot with understanding how VLOOKUP works exactly, although even by using your logic I still get syntax error. Does it matter if some fields are empty? (FYI: Column1 only has 100 rows, MOVIE_ID and AVERAGE_RATING have 5000. I tried changing it up to this `=VLOOKUP(B2;$A$2:$C$500;3;FALSE)`, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, its #NAAM? (Dutch for NAME), so it's indicating a syntax error I'm supposing. [link](https://i.imgur.com/WLOBQBC.png)

Comment: Is to possible to generate these function with your function wizadrd?

Comment: But you have VLOOKUP in your function list?

Comment: Yes, in dutch its VERT.ZOEKEN but its the exact same function, I used both and removed/added the 0 and FALSE at the end.

Comment: My excuses, I just noticed that I made a typo. Thank you for the help!